# CodeIgniter GAE SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I'm having an error using CodeIgniter

```
A Database Error Occurred
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
Filename: controllers/Template.php
Line Number: 15
```

Here is my code in application/database.php

[image: code snippet]

I tried using mysqli, but it failed. This error occurs after I change our Google Cloud from standard environment to flexible environment.

Comment: $db['default']  = array(
 'dsn'    => 'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/[instance];dbname=[name]',
 'username'  => 'root',
 'password'  => '[pass]',
 'database'  => '[db]',
 'dbdriver'  =>  'pdo',
 'dbprefix'  =>  '',
 'pconnect'  =>  FALSE,
 'db_debug'  =>  (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on'  =>  FALSE,
 'cachedir'  =>  '',
 'char_set'  =>  'utf8',
 'dbcollat'  =>  'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre'  =>  '',
 'encrypt'   =>  FALSE,
 'compress'   =>  FALSE,
 'stricton'   =>  FALSE,
 'failover'   =>  array(),
 'save_queries'  =>  TRUE
);

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'YOUR USERNAME',
    'password' => 'YOUR PASSWORD', if you set password in mysql
    'database' => 'YOUDATABASE',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => 'sss_',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```